# What can I do to improve this F# code?

Tags: .net, f#

I am learning F#, so I have been coming up with small blocks of code to help me get the hang of the language. I created the code below to be called from C# and subsequently save an uploaded file. How can I improve this code? All points of views are welcome.

```
open System.Web
open System.IO

type SaveUpload(file: HttpPostedFileBase, path : string) = 

    // get the file name
    let origFileName = file.FileName

    // create the path including filename
    let filePath = Path.Combine(path, origFileName)

    // directory check
    let directory = Directory.Exists(path)

    // create directory
    let createDir x = 
        match x with
        |false -> Directory.CreateDirectory(path) |> ignore
        |true -> ()

    // save file
    let saveFile = 
        createDir directory
        if directory 
        then file.SaveAs(filePath)
```

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I was unaware of code review. Will post there in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some quick thoughts:

- As you wrote it, the code is defining a type `SaveUpload`, but you are really implementing code that does some work - so I do not see why this would be a type. You can write it as a static member or a function (both will look as static methods to C#)
- I'm not sure if pattern matching on Booleans using `match` is really that useful here. It might be shorter to just use `if` (but pattern matching is great in more advanced cases)
- At the end, you are defining a variable `saveFile`, but this is just a value of type `unit` - all the code is already executed and the file is saved when someone calls the constructor. If you intended to make this a method, then it needs to take a unit value `()` as an argument.
- Similarly, `directory` is a value that is calculated just once - and so if the directory does not exist, your code creates it, but then does not save the file, because the `directory` value is still `false`.

So, if I wanted to write this as a function in a module, I'd go with something like this:

```
open System.Web
open System.IO

module FileHelpers = 
  let SaveUpload (file:HttpPostedFileBase) (path:string) = 

    // get the file name
    let origFileName = file.FileName

    // create the path including filename
    let filePath = Path.Combine(path, origFileName)

    // directory check
    let pathExists () = Directory.Exists(path)

    // create directory
    let createDir () = 
        if not (pathExists ()) then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path) |> ignore

    // save file
    createDir ()
    if pathExists() then
        file.SaveAs(filePath)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and great insight. Really excited about moving on to F# from C#. F# seems really amazing.

Comment: @user1206480 To make the dir creation logic tighter, you could `let dir = DirectoryInfo(path); if( not <| dir.Exists) dir.Create()` (note nothing to `ignore` from `Create()`) and you can then remove the guard on the `file.SaveAs()` as you'll have got an exception if there was a problem saving. There is also a `Path.GetDirectoryName( completePath)` which might be useful in other similar cases [but is unnecessary here as you already have the raw dir name as the `path` parameter].